# How to get the time of the next event in SystemC

Tags: systemc

Is there a function in SystemC which returns the time of the next event? Or if does not exist, then how to implement it?

For example I have clock model with 1 MHz frequency and I run the model with `sc_start(100, SC_NS)`.
The next scheduled event is at 500 ns.

The code looks like this:

```
..
sc_start(100, SC_NS);
next_time = get_next_event_time(); //get_next_event_time() should return with 500
..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sc_time_to_pending_activity()` to get the time until the earliest pending activity. More details are available in [IEEE Std 1666-2011](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf) at *4.5.7 Functions to detect pending activity*